# How to fix 'Invalid Object Name' error while importing sqlserver database from another server?

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I am trying to migrate a database (provided by the client) from remote sql server to local sqlserver instance.

I generated sql script using 'generate script' menu with sql server management studio. When I try to run that script in my local sqlserver I am getting error "Error: Invalid object name 'XXX'. On checking the script, it appears table 'XXX' indeed not created any where but its referenced in a select query.

Note, earlier I was facing error  with non existing path reference related fileGroup. Which I manually removed from the script which solve the issue. Also I tried setting true with option “Check for object existence" which haven't solved the 'Invalid object name' problem.

I was expecting sql script generated will be self contained have all tables necessary. Is there any option in while exporting in the SSMS which retains all necessary table/object?

Comment: Would it not be far simpler to just restore a backup and adjust the physical file locations of the MDF, LDF, and NDF (if present) files using the MOVE option?

Comment: I tried the same, however in my case source server is on  windows system while destination is  Sql-server image running on docker on MacOS. Which made mapping little complicated as I cant map 'C:\sql\xxx.mdf' on a path in docker.

Answer (score 0):

SSMS has lots of options about what it generates when scripting (set the defaults with Tools | Options | SQL Server Object Explorer | Scripting).

These options can be overridden when scripting (it is the Advanced button on the Set Scripting Options page of the wizard).

Equally maybe only a subset of database objects were selected when scripting.

(To be more specific I would need to know for more detail.)